# Help to compute the integral

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble to compute this integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^{3/2} e^{x/2} \ dx$  . Someone could give me a help to compute ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have a closed form in terms of elementary functions. However,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} I &=& \int_{0}^{1} x^{3/2} e^{x/2}\,dx = \sqrt{e}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{3/2} e^{-x/2}\,dx = \sqrt{e}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!}(1-x)^{3/2}x^n\,dx\\&=&\sqrt{e}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!}B(5/2,n+1)=\sqrt{e}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \Gamma(5/2)}{2^n \Gamma(n+7/2)}=\color{red}{6\sqrt{e}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+5)!!}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
that is a really fast converging series. The last term can be written as:
$$ \color{black}{2\sqrt{e}\left(-2+3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{DawsonF}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}, $$
where the [Dawson function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html) depends on $\operatorname{Erfi}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $I = e^{x/2}x^{3/2}-\displaystyle \int e^{x/2}x^{1/2}dx$.

$y = x^{1/2} \to x = y^2\to J = \displaystyle \int e^{y^2/2}y^2dy = \displaystyle \int yd\left(e^{y^2/2}\right)= ye^{y^2/2}- \displaystyle \int e^{y^2/2}dy$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{1}x^{3/2} e^{x/2} \ dx = [ x^{3/2} 2 e^{x/2} ]_0^1 - 3 \int_0^1  \sqrt{x} e^{x/2} dx$ by integration by parts, and the second integral is calculated by changing variables $t^2 = x$ but you will not have a closed form, because you'll end up with having to calculate a primitive of $\mapsto e^{y^2/2}$, for which you dont have a closed form.